# Drupal 8 Form won't load

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have an empty form in Drupal 8, looking like this:

In `JobFileUpload/src/Form/JobFileUploadForm.php`:

```
namespace \Drupal\JobFileUpload\Form;

use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class JobFileUploadForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'jobfileupload_jobfileuploadform';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }
}
```

The routing looks like this:

In `JobFileUpload.routing.yml`:

```
JobFileUpload.UploadForm:
  path: '/file/upload/'
  defaults: 
    _title: 'Job File Upload'
    _form: '\Drupal\JobFileUpload\Form\JobFileUploadForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

and finally, my in `JobFileUpload.info.yml`:

```
name: Job File Upload
description: Shows a file upload form. 
package: Custom
type: module
core: 8.x
```

Refreshing the cache throws the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class JobFileUploadForm, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/drupaldev/modules/JobFileUpload/src/Form/JobFileUploadForm.php on line 34, ...

Comment: Are there any classes that are autogenerated that might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the trailing slash at the end of the route path was the culprit. Removed it, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your routing file code with below code
JobFileUpload.UploadForm:
  path: '/file/upload'
  defaults: 
    _title: 'Job File Upload'
    _form: '\Drupal\JobFileUpload\Form\JobFileUploadForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

Or change the name of form Ex: JOBUploadForm

Answer (score 0):

Also the namespace may be a cause: in this case may be

```
namespace Drupal\JobFileUpload\Form;
```

instead of

```
namespace \Drupal\JobFileUpload\Form;
```